# SQL query 'Join'

Tags: sql, sql-server

TABLE A >>

```
ItemNo  Name
1       Item1
2       Item2
3       Item3
4       Item4
```

TABLE B >>

```
ItemNo  Status
1       available
1       onhold
1       Sold
1       Transit
------------------
2       available
2       onhold
2       Sold
-----------------
3       Transit
-----------------
4       onhold
```

There are four status on table B `onhold`,`available`,`sold`,`Transit`

Expected result: if anyone of the `itemNo` in table B has on either `available` or `Transit`,
then I need to get only the table A record of that `ItemNo`

Output:

Table A:

```
ItemNo  Name            
1       Item1       
2       Item2
3       Item3
```

Please advise on how to write MS SQL query for this. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: MSSQL or MySQL? MSSQL is Microsoft SQL-Server.

Comment: its MS sql @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You can solve with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA ta 
WHERE tA.ItemNo IN 
    (
        SELECT tB.ItemNo 
        FROM tableB tB
        WHERE tB.Status in ('available','Transit') 
          AND tB.ItemNo = ta.ItemNo
    )
```

Comment: *Always* specify table references in subqueries, or you may get incorrect results `WHERE tB.Status in ('available','Transit') AND tB.ItemNo = ta.ItemNo`

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get just one row from table A.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM TableA AS a
JOIN TableB AS b ON a.itemNo = b.itemNo
WHERE b.status in ('available', 'Transit')
```